How to Arrange 21 Uniquely Sized Squares to Form a Perfect Square?
I’m tackling a geometric puzzle where I have 21 squares, each with a different integer side length. The goal is to arrange these squares so that they perfectly fill a larger square without leaving any gaps or overlaps. Each square must keep its given size in the arrangement.
To give you some context, this puzzle is similar to tiling problems where you need to fit various shapes into a specific layout. In this case, the layout is a perfect square, and the challenge is to figure out if it’s possible to achieve this with the 21 uniquely sized squares.
What’s a potential approach to solve this? Are there any known strategies for arranging uniquely sized squares into a larger square?

It would be useful to know what the sizes of the squares are. The most obvious "general" approach is to check that the total area covered by the small squares is itself a square number, but I assume you've already done that. This is probably what you're looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square

For the case of $21$ (different) squares, one way to tell whether (and how) the squares fit together is to cheat: compare them to the known unique "simple perfect squared square" of order $21$. Noted in the Wikipedia entry I cited above, additional background information is found on the "SPSS, order 21" page at squaring.net.

One approach is to formulate this as an instance of integer linear programming, and apply an off-the-shelf ILP solver.
Let $s_i$ denote the side length of the $i$th square.  Introduce (real-valued) variables $x_i,y_i$, intended to represent the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the $i$th square.  We have $0 \le x_i$, $x_i + s_i \le S$, $0 \le y_i$, $y_i + s_i \le S$ where $S$ is the side length of the larger square.  I'll assume that the total area of the squares is what it needs to be, i.e., $\sum_i s_i^2 = S^2$.
For this to be a valid solution, we require that no two squares overlap.  Two squares $A,B$ do not overlap iff one or more of the following four conditions is true: $A$ is to the left of $B$; $A$ is above $B$; $A$ is to the right of $B$; $A$ is below $B$.  This can be encoded in ILP as follows.  For each pair $i,j$ of squares, introduce four boolean (zero-or-one integer) variables $l_{i,j},a_{i,j},r_{i,j},b_{i,j}$, representing those four conditions.  Add the equality $l_{i,j}+a_{i,j}+r_{i,j}+b_{i,j} \ge 1$.  Also if $l_{i,j}=1$ we want to enforce $x_i+s_i \le x_j$, which can be done via the inequality $x_i+s_i \le x_j + S(1-l_{i,j})$.  Introduce similar inequalities for $a_{i,j},r_{i,j},b_{i,j}$.
This gives an ILP instance that encodes the requirements to form a valid tiling of the square.  Then use an off-the-shelf ILP solver to search for a valid solution.
There might be better algorithms.  I suggest searching the literature on 'squaring the square' to see what methods have been used there and whether they can be applied to your problem, then coming back here to write an answer that contains a summary of the literature.
